# I have trouble adding class to angular td

Tags: angular

I want to color all the cells the match with the data I am receiving from an API
when I trigger colorMatchingRecords()
When I trigger the colorMatchingRecords() nothing happens on the HTML table

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i5ni21?

```js
Results: any = []
getResults() {
  this.service.getData().subscribe(res => {
    this.Results = res
  })

  // this is how the Results look like Results=[{name:'Mike',age:34,gender:'Male'}............]
}
colorMatchingRecords() {

  let first = $(' tbody tr td:nth-child(1)')
  let second = $(' tbody tr td:nth-child(2)')
  let third = $(' tbody tr td:nth-child(3)')
  this.Results.forEach(elm => {
    if (elm.name == first.text()) {
      first.addClass('match')
    }
    if (elm.gender == second.text()) {
      second.addClass('match')
    }
    if (elm.age == third.text()) {
      third.addClass('match')
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.match {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table">

  <table>
    <thead class="thead">
      <tr class="tr">
        <th class="th" scope="col">Name</th>
        <th class="th" scope="col">Gender</th>
        <th class="th" scope="col">Age</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="tbody" *ngFor="let el of details; even as even;x as index">
      <tr class="tr" id="{{x}}" [ngClass]="{'even': even}">
        <td class="td">{{el.name}}</td>
        <td class="td">{{el.gender}}</td>
        <td class="td">{{el.age}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: when do you execute colorMatchingRecords()?

Comment: I have a button with a click event

Comment: Could you make an example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/)? I don't think I understand fully what you are trying to do.

Comment: You didn't copy the right url. You have to select "SHARE" in the left, next to "FORK", and copy the url that it gives you.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i5ni21?

Comment: Sorry I have changed the url, I copied a wrong url

Comment: Why jQuery though? Angular can do this much easier and better?

Comment: @ MikeOne how do I do it , I read about rendere2 but but I was confused if how to implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid completely using j-query in Angular *and in general, since javascript can do most of it*.

You could add a new attribute to your object, like `class` and then update them with your logic, when you do click on `colorMatchingRecords()`.

Then, inside the html, you add the class into the list of class your `tr` have

This working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hd8yca?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

HTML

```html
<div class="table">
  <table>
    <thead class="thead">
      <tr class="tr">
        <th class="th" scope="col">Name</th>
        <th class="th" scope="col">Gender</th>
        <th class="th" scope="col">Age</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody class="tbody" *ngFor="let el of details; even as even; x as index">
      <!-- see the {{el.class}} -->
      <tr class="tr {{ el.class }}" id="{{ x }}" [class.even]="even"> 
        <td class="td">{{ el.name }}</td>
        <td class="td">{{ el.gender }}</td>
        <td class="td">{{ el.age }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<button (click)="colorMatchingRecords()">Color Records</button>
```

ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  Results: any = [
    { name: 'John', age: 34, gender: 'Male' },
    { name: 'Ben', age: 50, gender: 'Male' },
    { name: 'Mike', age: 34, gender: 'Male' },
    { name: 'Seth', age: 34, gender: 'Male' },
  ];
  
  // Adding type, to make it accept `class` being unset at the beginning
  details: { name: string; age: number; gender: string; class?: string }[] = [
    { name: 'John', age: 22, gender: 'Male' },
    { name: 'Ken', age: 34, gender: 'Male' },
    { name: 'Ruth', age: 22, gender: 'Female' },
    { name: 'Seth', age: 14, gender: 'Male' },
    { name: 'Ben', age: 52, gender: 'Male' },
  ];

  colorMatchingRecords() {
    for (let index = 0; index < this.Results.length; index++) {
      const elem = this.Results[index];

      console.log(elem, this.details[index]);
      // If the element have the same name, update add the `match` class
      this.details[index].class =
        this.details[index] && elem.name == this.details[index].name
          ? 'match'
          : '';
    }
  }
}
```